# Unit test async UI change in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, xctestexpectation

I am trying to unit test a custom `UIView`, which changes the UI asynchronously. This is the code for the custom view:

```
import UIKit

class DemoView: UIView {
    
    var label: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        setup()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        self.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func setLabel(_ text: String) {
        Task {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(100))
            label.text = text
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test, that after calling the `setLabel(_:)` function, the text on the label did change, therefore I wrote the following test:

```
@MainActor
func testExample() async throws {
    let demoView = DemoView(frame: .zero)
    XCTAssertEqual(demoView.label.text, nil)
    
    demoView.setLabel("New Text")
    let expectLabelChange = expectation(for: NSPredicate(block: { _, _ in
        demoView.label.text != nil
    }), evaluatedWith: demoView.label)
    await waitForExpectations(timeout: 5)
    
    XCTAssertEqual(demoView.label.text, "New Text")
}
```

But the exception runs into a timeout and the assert fails. When I set breakpoints, I can see that the `Task` inside `setLabel(_:)` is executed, but never reenters after sleeping, even though the timeout is long enough. Only after the `waitForExpectations` finishes, the task inside `setLabel(_:)` is continued, however this is too late for the assert to catch the changes.

How can I write the test, so that the `Task` in `setLabel(_:)` continues?

**NOTE:** The code is adjusted for demonstrating the issue. In the real app I call an API instead of sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `async` testing for this, and you shouldn't use it. `setLabel` is not `async`, and you're using an expectation! This test will pass (and I've rewritten a few minor things along the way):

```
@MainActor func testExample() {
    let demoView = DemoView(frame: .zero)
    XCTAssertEqual(demoView.label.text, nil)

    demoView.setLabel("New Text")
    let predicate = NSPredicate { _, _ in
        demoView.label.text != nil
    }
    let expectLabelChange = expectation(for: predicate, evaluatedWith: nil)
    wait(for: [expectLabelChange], timeout: 5)

    XCTAssertEqual(demoView.label.text, "New Text")
}
```

Even better, remove the `@MainActor` from your `setLabel` call; you can then remove it from the test function too.

---

Under what circumstances would `async` for the test be appropriate? If `setLabel` were `async`! Suppose you rewrite `setLabel` like this:

```
func setLabel(_ text: String) async throws {
    try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(100))
    label.text = text
}
```

*Now* you need your tests to be `async` — and now you don't need an expectation! Look how simple everything becomes:

```
@MainActor
func testExample() async throws {
    let demoView = DemoView(frame: .zero)
    XCTAssertEqual(demoView.label.text, nil)

    try await demoView.setLabel("New Text")
    XCTAssertEqual(demoView.label.text, "New Text")
}
```

Comment: Irrelevant here, but calling an NSObject method `setLabel` is a really bad idea.