# Unit test assertion on a coordinator fails because the view controller takes some time to be pushed on the navigation stack

Tags: swift, unit-testing, uikit, coordinator-pattern

I’m trying to unit test a coordinator I created. The way I’m doing it is using the following assertion:

```swift
func test_example() {
    // call a coordinator func that should perform a navigation (using pushViewController()) from AViewController to BViewController.

    XCTAssert(coordinator.navigationController.topViewController is BViewController)
}
```

The problem with my approach is that, sometimes, `BViewController` takes time to be pushed, and because of that the assertion runs before the view controller is added to the navigation stack, causing the unit test to fail.

In order to solve the problem, I configured an `expectation` and I called `expectation.fulfill()` inside a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()` closure.

I don’t like the approach I took. It’s kinda hacky. I’d love to know if there is a *better*, *cleaner* way to solve my problem without using `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make (and wait for) a *predicate expectation* asserting that `coordinator.navigationController.topViewController is BViewController`.

Comment: For example code, see the first code in my https://stackoverflow.com/a/74763844/341994

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the concise explanation. Already implemented it and it's working.

Comment: Waiting for a predicate is such a useful and common thing to do that many programmers have a `waitFor` method that takes a Boolean expression (as a closure) and simply generates the predicate, the expectation, and the `wait` call for you; thus this becomes a one-liner.